# Export result profile from Dataprep

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataprep

I'm using Dataprep to run a quick data quality profile on my source data. My goal is to output this profile into a sheet. I've followed the steps provided in the [Dataprep docs](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/html/Profile-Your-Source-Data_57344603) and can now view the profile of my data on the Job Results page. Is there anyway I can export this data profile into sheets or as a csv?